# Filtrando dados do json com atributo do schema

Tags: javascript, json, api, mongoose

Eu tenho um `JSON` neste formato:

```
{
 "1": {
   "cidade":"cidade1",
   "name":"nome1"
 },
 "2": {
   "cidade":"cidade2",
   "name":"nome2"
 }
}
```

e preciso filtrar os dados desse json. Pra isso eu fiz um `model.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MySchema = new Schema({cod: Number, cidade: String, nome: String});

module.exports = mongoose.model('My', MySchema);
```

e um `routes.js`

```
module.exports = function(router, My) {

    router.route('/my')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            My.find(function(err, my) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json(my);
            });
        });

    router.route('/my/:my_id')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            My.findById(req.params.my_id, function(err, my) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json(my);
            });
        })
}
```

O meu problema é o seguinte, eu quero filtrar pelo meu atributo `cod` e não pelo id gerado pelo mongoose de uma forma onde eu digitasse `/my/1` e ele me retornasse

```
{
 "1": {
   "cidade":"cidade1",
   "name":"nome1"
 }
}
```

Já tentei de várias formas mas não consegui. Tentei via query:

```
router.route('/my/:cod')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            My.find(function(err, my) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json(my);
            }).where('my.cod').equals(req.params.cod);
        })
```

Tentei setar um Custom Id, mas nenhuma dessas formas funcionaram. Algum ideia do que eu possa fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então seu banco esta alimentado ok no formato {cod: Number, cidade: String, nome: String} ?? Primeiro passo a se conferir..

Pelo pouco que estou estudando até o momento o seu json deveria ser tratado pois ele esta tratando os campos "1", "2" como campo composto e vc nao tem a referencia a cod e sim a campos 1, 2.

Ex.:

```
mongoose-user-test> db.teste.find()
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57464d7729950798b4ad3d85"),
  "1": {
  "cidade": "cidade1",
  "name": "nome1"
},
 "2": {
"cidade": "cidade2",
"name": "nome2"
 }
}
```

Agora se o seu json esta formatado assim:

```
{"cod": "1","cidade":"cidade1","name":"nome1"}
{"cod":"2", "cidade":"cidade2", "name":"nome2"}
```

Se sim você consegue fazer um find simples:

```
My.find({cod: req.params.cod }, function(err, data){...});
```

Ex:

```
mongoose-user-test> db.teste.find()
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57464f5529950798b4ad3d86"),
  "cod": "2",
  "cidade": "cidade2",
  "name": "nome2"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57464f5529950798b4ad3d87"),
  "cod": "1",
  "cidade": "cidade1",
  "name": "nome1"
}

mongoose-user-test> db.teste.find({cod:"2"})
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57464f5529950798b4ad3d86"),
  "cod": "2",
  "cidade": "cidade2",
  "name": "nome2"
}
```

Outra coisa a observar que ele esta tratando todos os elementos do seu json como string.. Igual na query acima se eu fizesse o find com {cod:2} não seria retornado nenhum elemento.